# presto syntax for csv external table with array in one of the fields

Tags: arrays, csv, presto, amazon-athena

I'm having trouble creating a table in Athena - that points at files with the following format:
string, string, string, array.

when I wrote the file - I delimited the array items with '|'. 
I delimited each line with '\n' and each column with ','.

so for example, a row in my CSV would look like that:

`Garfield, 15, orange, fish|milk|lasagna`

in hive (according to the documentation i read)- when creating a table with a row delimited format - while stating the delimiters you can state a 'collection items' delimiter - that states the delimiter between elements in array columns.
I could not find an equivalent for Presto in the documentation,

Is anyone aware if it's possible, if so - what is the format, or where can I find it?

i tried "guessing" many forms, including 'collection items', none seem to work.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `cats`(
  `name` string, 
  `age` string, 
  `color` string, 
  `foods` array<string>)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
  COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '|'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'some-location'
```

Would really appreciate any insight, Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to AWS Athena docs on [using SerDe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/serde-about.html), your guess was 100% correct.

> In general, Athena uses the LazySimpleSerDe if you do not specify a `ROW FORMAT`, or if you specify `ROW FORMAT DELIMITED`
>
> ```sql
> ROW FORMAT
> DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
> ESCAPED BY '\\'
> COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '|'
> MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY ':'
> ```

Now, when I simply tried your DDL statement, I would get

```
line 1:8: no viable alternative at input 'create external'
```

However by deleting `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`, I was able to create table schema in meta catalog

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `cats`(
  `name` string, 
  `age` string, 
  `color` string, 
  `foods` array<string>)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
  COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '|'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'some-location'
```

Sample file with lines as shown in your file would get parsed correctly and I was able to do `UNNEST` on `foods` column:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM "cats" 
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(foods) as t(food)
```

which resulted in 
[image: sample_result]

Moreover, it was also enough to simply swap lines `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'` and `COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '|'` for query to work (although I don't have an explanation for it)

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `cats`(
  `name` string, 
  `age` string, 
  `color` string, 
  `foods` array<string>)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','   
  COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '|'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'some-location'
```

Comment: Yes you are right, i got to the same conclusion but in a different way - 
the problem is the order, if you set the collection items before the lines delimieter it works.

Answer (score 2):

(Note: this answer is applicable to Presto in general, but not to Athena)

Currently you cannot set collection delimiter in Presto.
Please create a feature request @ https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/

Note, we plan to provide generic support for table properties to address cases like this holistically -- https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/954. You can track the issue and [associated pull request](https://github.com/prestosql/presto/pull/1176) for updates.

Comment: Hey , i changed the order of the delimiters and it worked, so that's strange.
if i use this order:
`
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
  COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '|'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
`
it created the table and recognized the array

Comment: @liormayn i overlooked you're using Athena. While Athena is hosted Presto, it actually uses Hive syntax for DDLs. My answer was about Presto only.

Answer (score 0):

I'm use presto engine creating a hive table , set collection delimiter in Presto, for example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (        
       id bigint COMMENT 'ID',                   
       type varchar COMMENT 'TYPE',                   
       content varchar COMMENT 'CONTENT',          
       create_time timestamp(3) COMMENT 'CREATE TIME',          
       pt varchar                                    
)                                                 
COMMENT 'create time 2021/11/04 11:27:53'` 
WITH (                                             
       format = 'TEXTFILE',                            
       partitioned_by = ARRAY['pt'],                   
       textfile_field_separator = U&'\0001'            
)
```